# HtmlUnit Accessing Basic Authentication Dialogue

Tags: java, web, basic-authentication, htmlunit

I am trying to connect to a page that requires http basic authentication. I have already accomplished that by passing the credentials through the request header in the web client.

But my **first goal** is to be able to **read the contents of the "Authentication Required" pop up dialogue box**.

**Second** would be to **fill out the username and password and then finally click on the "login" button in the dialogue**.

Everytime I try to access such page using HtmlUnit It gives me 401 Unauthorized page , the page that you get after you click on "cancel" or "login" with invalid credentials.

**Does HtmlUnit API have the capability to access the contents of the basic authentication pop up dialogue ?** Appreciate your assistance/suggestions.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to *read the contents of the "Authentication Required" pop up dialogue box*. The objective of the dialog is to authorize you. You claim to have already accomplished that. Then, what issue are you trying to solve by reading that dialog? (Clearly, it is not authenticating).

Comment: I have noticed that that the dialogue box usually says something like "the server http://somesite.com:port requires a username and password .The server says: some realm name"

Comment: What i want to read is the realm name (protected space on that server) and then fill out the username/password , click on login - all using HtmlUnit.

Comment: Since HtmlUnit is a browser simulation tool it should be equipped to let us enter the user/pass and then click on the login button on the dialogue box to retrieve the actual page.

Comment: I see now. I agree with you on that. Anyway, regarding getting the realm name, have you tried taking a look at the response header "WWW-Authenticate"? I get this: WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="here_goes_the_value_you_need"

Comment: yes i have looked at that. Its an attribute that is sent with the 401 unauthorized response from the server asking the client for the auth information. Yes the realm name is what gets displayed in the dialog box.